# How to easily see the name of the current method

Tags: eclipse

When I used Visual Studio with C++ there was a nice combo box where you could always easily see the name of the method in which the cursor was. Is there something similar in eclipse for Java (except of Outline, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch on a breadcrumb like bar in the top of Java editors. Right-click a Java editor an select *Show in breadcrumb* or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

[image: Breadcrumb]

You can also select elements of every level, the dropdowns also allow to expand into deeper levels.

Answer (score 1):

if you hover your cursor over the closing bracket of a method or class  then it will show you the name of the method/class that the bracket belongs too

Comment: +1 for the nice function, however it's not what I'm looking for. When you're in the middle of a method and you don't know which method is, it's easier to go up to declaration than go down to the closing bracket ;)